# "Cannot set property defaults of #<n>" error while integrating GrapesJS-blocks-boostrap4 plugin

Tags: reactjs, grapesjs

I am trying to add grapesjs-blocks-bootstrap4 plugin in my grapesjs editor in reactjs. When I try adding it, I get the following error.

````
```TypeError: Cannot set property defaults of #<n> which has only a getter
    at grapes.min.js:2:1
    at Module.It (grapes.min.js:2:1)
    at Function.$ [as extend] (grapes.min.js:2:1)
    at vr (grapesjs-blocks-bootstrap4.min.js:11:1) ```
````

I tried deleting the node modules and installing them again, but still had the same issue.
Thank you for your help in advance.